# How can a list of words, after inner_join() with the AFINN lexicon, still have more elements than the lexicon?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

For my R statistics homework I've converted the text of "Pride and Prejudice" into a data frame with each row containing one word. The data frame had 37,246 rows after removing stop words. Then I used inner_join() to combine the data frame with the AFINN sentiment lexicon. The resulting data frame had 6,065 rows while the AFINN lexicon only has 2,477 rows. How can this be? Shouldn't the resulting data frame have at most the same number of rows as the lexicon?

I tried finding out which words are in the data frame but not the lexicon, but the code doesn't work:

```
afinn_sentiments %>% filter(!word %in% afinn)
```

afinn_sentiments is the data frame with 6,065 rows, while afinn contains the afinn lexicon.

This code still gives 6,065 rows, which is impossible.

Can someone please help explain this?

Comment: multiple the same words in afinn_sentiments. Inner_join just combines the datasets. If you have multiple the same words, which you will have in the text, you get more records. Completely normal. You can check this by grouping the words and counting them.

Comment: Oh yikes I forgot about that - thanks!